# How do you say that something is "on a website"? Which preposition to use?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

For saying that something is *on a website*, I have seen at least four different prepositions:

> - La demando estas **je** Stack Exchange
> - La afiŝo estas **en** Reddit
> - La pepaĵo estas **ĉe** Twitter
> - Ĝi estas **sur** Facebook

Is there a better/best way to express this idea?

Comment: [It is "Stack Exchange", not "StackExchange"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name").

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that. I guess people type it without the space, including me, because there is no space in the logo at the top left of the website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran a search on the phrase 'la retejo' using tekstaro.com, and found that all the relevant results used 'en'. Some examples are below:

- Aktualaj informoj pri HELA estas en la retejo de Varsovia Vento.
- La suba teksto estas ĉerpita el pli ampleksa raporto en la retejo de FEB.
- 277 elektronikaj libroj en formato PDF, kun entute 39329 paĝoj, estas senpage elŝuteblaj en la retejo eLibroj.
- ...oni devas musklaki sur butono en la retejo por elŝuti la spektotan programeron.
- Ĝi estas en la ĝenerala informa turisma retejo pri Vilnius.

This suggests that 'en' is the most commonly used preposition when talking about something being on a website.

Comment: Even though the author of the PMEG grammar, Bertilo Wennergren, uses the term *TTT‑ejo* instead of *retejo*, [he, too, uses the preposition *en*](http://bertilow.com/aliaj).

Comment: One of my rules of thumb with Esperanto usage is to model my own after experienced speakers, especially those who are multilingual.  Bertilo is one I look to for guidance.  If you haven't already downloaded a copy of [PMEG, Plena Manlibro de Esperanta Gramatiko](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/), do it today.  It's written entirely in Esperanto, but Bertilo's writing is straightforward and easily to follow.  It's an excellent reference.

Answer (score 7):

Prepositions are one of the most inconsistent areas for translation.  All it takes for me to remember that is to remind myself that while I was "in college" here in the US, my Canadian friends were "at University".  We quite literally mean the same thing.

StackEdo is technically correct in suggesting *je*, although it isn't the best choice.  *Je* is the preposition to use when there isn't a better one.  It's not the best choice here, but it would be understood.  As a fallback when you aren't sure, you can use it.

However, I agree that *en* is the best choice.  *Ĉe* is good, but I have a reason for choosing *en* over it.  When we talk about websites, it's common to refer to their "content".  Content is something that is contained in something.  That's the primary use of "in" in English and "*en*" in Esperanto.  The content of a website is "in" the website in much the same way that articles are in a magazine.  The best argument for any choice of a translation is always one based on the concept being translated, not just the word.

Answer (score 1):

Take this with a grain of salt, because I'm very rusty.

I like *ĉe*, because it seems to be derived from French *chez* which means (most literally) ‘at the house of’, and thus makes a good metaphor for material residing with (hosted by) a website.

Answer (score 1):

People generally use "ĉe" as the word for "@", so "ĉe (retejo)" strikes me as a good option.

Answer (score -1):

je means on

en means in

cxe means at

sur means on

I think sur refers to a physical thing, like a cat on a table, a shoe on your head etc

So I think in this instance, je would be the right word to use.

Comment: “sur” can also refer to a photo on the wall or on the screen.

Comment: Literally translating prepositions can be very misleading. Also, how do you figure that *je* means *on*?

Comment: Actually, I think *je* is quite good. It's meant to resolve situations when no single preposition is a good fit, after all. And if one is – well, then by definition *je* is also acceptable.